# Linux bash - how to make a softlink for I/O redirect

Tags: linux, bash

I am using `xclip` in order to copy the shell output into the clipboard by the following command:

```
cat filename.ext | xclip -i -selection clipboard
```

i which to create a soft link for the command after the pipe, i.e. `xclip -i -selection clipboard`, in order to have it short. for instance, executing the same thing as above but shorter

```
cat filename.ext | clip
```

I would appreciate if one could elaborate on how it should be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is an 'alias', not a softlink: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/aliases.html

```
alias clip="xclip -i -selection clipboard"
```

Answer (score 3):

`xclip` can take a file on the command line, so there is no need to use `cat`. A shell function can reduce this to a simple command:

```
function clip () {
    xclip -i -selection clipboard $1
}

clip filename.ext
```